# Google Search impressions stopped updating

Tags: google-search-console

Search impressions went from 0 to 1350 within a week then suddenly stopped. Also I have requested indexing for the main website url and it has never been crawled by Google Bot. What could be the issue? I have added three properties: http://site-url.com , https://site-url.com and https://www.site-url.com but none is updating search impressions.

[image]
Both  http://site-url.com and https://site-url.com have been indexed by google crawl. However
https://www.site-url.com has not been indexed but I have requested indexing(1 month ago);I have also requested a few more times.

All sitemaps are added and accessible to search console.
What could be the cause of the issue?

I did robots.txt tests and none of the crawlers is blocked. see image below

[image: Robots txt test results]

Comment: Try the options here - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7474347?hl=en

Comment: @anmolsharma I have gone through all these recommendations, I tried them about 2 weeks ago but still no noticeable change

Comment: Make sure Google Bot is blocked by the webserver (or proxy) hosting the website. Here is the list of them - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943

Comment: Still no update on the impressions. 
I checked coverage and got this error: "Duplicate without user-selected canonical".